# Google App Script- Check value of cell against col A, then edit corresponding col B

Tags: google-apps-script

so i have the following code that works perfectly for our purposes, it took me a long time to put together, and I know that is a horribly inefficient solution to my problem. In the interest of space, ive only linked the first if statement. This is repeated 14 more times with the other outcomes.

The problem is that we are going to have over 100 items soon, and while this works for 5, im afraid it is going to be far too much work and run very slowly to replicate.

```
  function onEdit(event) {
var invinput = ss.getRange("L16").getValue();
var iteminput = ss.getRange("J16").getValue();
var item1 = ss.getRange("A2").getValue();
var item2 = ss.getRange("A3").getValue();
var item3 = ss.getRange("A4").getValue();
var item4 = ss.getRange("A5").getValue();
var item5 = ss.getRange("A6").getValue();  
var inv1 = ss.getRange("B2").getValue();
var inv2 = ss.getRange("B3").getValue();  
var inv3 = ss.getRange("B4").getValue();  
var inv4 = ss.getRange("B5").getValue(); 
var inv5 = ss.getRange("B6").getValue(); 
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("invinputlog");
var itemList = ss.getRange(1,0,1000)
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  if(s.getName() == "IMI" && r.getColumn() == 14 && r.getValue() == "add" && (iteminput == item1)) {
      ss.getRange("B2").setValue(invinput+inv1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target);
    ss.getRange("restockInput").clear();}
```

I've found a lot of solutions that are kind of helpful,some "for" statements that i tested, but I couldn't quite figure it out.

My question is that instead of having to compare "item1 == itemInput" for every item we have,   I would like it to be something like

```
if iteminput == (anything in column A) {
ss.getRange("Cell B next to Cell A that matches iteminput").setValue
(invinput+"cell B that is next to cell A that matches iteminput");}
```

Thank you in advance if anyone has any ideas, I really enjoy these projects, so even getting me on the right track would be great. I am happy to figure it out myself, I'm just a little stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have 100 items, then it will be slow, as you say.  What is slow is the access to the spreadsheet itself (what is fastest is the in-memory manipulation of every other 'command' which does not access the spreadsheet).  So, for example, if you write the script to do ss.getRange("A3").getValue() one hundred times then this is going to be slow.

If I were to approach your scripting problem I would fetch all the values which are on the spreadsheet just the once (per onEdit of course) using something like `var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();`

This will create a 2Dimensional array, of the nature

```
[
 [A1,   B1,   C1,   ... L1  ],
 [A2,   B2,   C2,   ... L2  ],
...
...
 [A100, B100, C100, ... L100]
]
```

You have the 'outer' array which holds multiple 'inner' arrays, each representing a row of the sheet, from the first† row up to the last row where there is any cell containing data and as wide as the first† column up to last column with any cell with data (every blank cell in between will be in the array too, which will be represented by empty string `''` )

† .getDataRange() defines the range, from first to last-with-data, as above.  You can use other range definitions too, e.g. getRange("A1:L100") ; nevertheless, the 2D nature of this range, and thus .getValues() will still be there.

Then you will have to manipulate this 2D array within google apps script.  You can google search [for loop in javascript OR google apps script](https://www.google.com/search?q=for%20loop%20in%20js%20OR%20%22google%20apps%20script%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab) to show you the code, which will be like:

```
for (var i = 0; i<values.length; i ++){
// YOUR CODE to manipulate this for..loop
}
```

The i variable within this for..loop increments each loop through YOUR CODE; thus it is the analog to each row (except it starts at zero i.e. one less than the row which starts at 1). So you will use i to reference each row in values.  And you will have, as the second dimension, 0 as ColA, 1 as ColB etc to 11 as ColL
e.g. in the fourth loop, i will be 3, so `values[i][1]` will reference cell B4.
In this manner, withing one or a few line(s) of code within a for..loop, using i, you can compare 100 (or many more) rows.

You would do your `if` comparison as part of YOUR CODE within the for..loop.
When your if comparison finds a match, you should stop the loop running using the [break](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=js%20break&oq=js%20break&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1888j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) statement. This will fix the var i, which you can then use within more script below the for..loop to write back to the spreadsheet.  For this, I would consider using [google apps script range.offset](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=google%20apps%20script%20range.offset&oq=google%20apps%20script%20range.offset&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l3.597j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

(Note: your actual use case may be more complicated than I have indicated above, particularly in the code that you would need to write to achieve your required comparison (the `if` within the loop).  However, your solution will almost certainly require the getValues() call to the spreadsheet so as to not make 100 getValue() calls, and thus you will have to work with 2D arrays.)